# Saving pre-loaded values in memory - Swift/SwiftUI

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui

I have a class of "questions" - basically cards that store text, a color, and a few other properties.

One of these properties is a favorite button. I have it set as a class so that a user can click on a heart icon to favorite that question.

This is persisting through that version of the app, but every time I restart the app, all my favorites disappear. There is no user data stored on the app, just this list of which questions are favorited. Do I have to use UserDefaults in order to store that data? Or is there some other way I can get that to persist across launches of the app (and also even if they update the version of the app?)

Here is the class:

```
class Question: Hashable, Identifiable, Codable, Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: Question, rhs: Question) -> Bool {
        let areEqual = lhs.id == rhs.id
        return areEqual
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }
    
    var id = UUID()
    var text: String
    var color: String
    var foregroundColor: String?
    var submittedBy: String?
    var favorited: Bool = false
    
    
    init (text: String, color: String, submittedBy: String? = "") {
        self.text = text
        self.color = color
    }
}
```

And an example variable with a "deck" of questions:

```
var whoQs: [Question] = [
    Question(text: "Who are you with when you feel the best?", color: "Who", submittedBy: "Testing Person"),
    Question(text: "Who do you let inform you?", color: "Who"),
    Question(text: "Who do you miss right now?", color: "Who")
]
```

And here is how I'm toggling the favorites item:

```
Button(action: {
                        currentQuestions.last?.favorited.toggle()
                        print("\(currentQuestions.last?.text) is favorited:  \(currentQuestions.last?.favorited)")
                    }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: currentQuestions.last?.favorited ?? false ? "heart.fill" : "heart")
                           // .foregroundColor(.black)
                            .imageScale(.large)
                    }).padding()
                    .disabled(!shareQuestionVisible)
```

Comment: Yes, for your case using the UserDefaults is the simplest variant.

Comment: UserDefaults or better CoreData